# Limiting instances types on aws sagemaker via iam policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to limit sagemker studio from launching anything that is 48xl, 32xl, or 24xl

here is the IAM policy but not sure why its not working,

```
        {
        "Action": [
            "sagemaker:CreateApp"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Sid": "BlockSagemaker",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                    "*.*.48xlarge",
                    "*.*.32xlarge",
                    "*.*.24xlarge",
                    "system",
                    "default"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "not sure why its not working," - so why not to use it it and check if its working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Testing out the policy should help, but without "system", "default".

Here is a sample that worked for me, it restricts use of any instance except `ml.t3.medium` and `ml.t3.xlarge`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "sagemaker:CreateApp",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotLike": {
                    "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                        "ml.t3.medium",
                        "default",
                        "system",
                        "ml.t3.xlarge"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use the following, it should restrict starting of any instance of 24xl, 32xl or 48xl to back you sagemaker notebook.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "sagemaker:CreateApp",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                        "*.*.48xlarge",
                        "*.*.32xlarge",
                        "*.*.24xlarge"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference:

1. [Restricting Instances to specific type](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1499#issuecomment-850381743)
2. [Allowing Instance of specific type](https://repost.aws/questions/QUd77APmdHTx-2FZCvZfS6Qg/can-i-limit-the-type-of-instances-that-data-scientists-can-launch-for-training-jobs-in-sagemaker)